Which runtime should be faster?
I implemented two solutions to Leetcode problem 988: one that creates a list of strings and sorts it to return the smallest (lexicographically) and another that just keeps track of the smallest throughout the generation process.
My analysis of the runtimes of the two would be O(nlogn) and O(n) respectively, so why is LeetCode telling me that the second implementation is 5ms slower overall?
Fist Solution:
class Solution:
    def smallestFromLeaf(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> str:
        d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
        words = []

        def dfs(node, string):
            if not node.left and not node.right:
                words.append((string + d[node.val])[::-1])
            if node.left:
                dfs(node.left, string + d[node.val])
            if node.right:    
                dfs(node.right, string + d[node.val])

        dfs(root, '')
        return sorted(words)[0]

Second Solution:
class Solution:
def smallestFromLeaf(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> str:
    d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
    shortest = None

    def dfs(node, string):
        if not node.left and not node.right:
            nonlocal shortest
            if not shortest:
                shortest = (string + d[node.val])[::-1]
            else:
                shortest = min(shortest, (string + d[node.val])[::-1])
        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left, string + d[node.val])
        if node.right:    
            dfs(node.right, string + d[node.val])

    dfs(root, '')
    return shortest


maybe use module time to measure how fast are both version. you can use time to check which part is the slowest. Eventually you could use tools like profiler to check which functions are the slowest.

Big-O calculation won't necessarily tell you which algorithm will be faster. It tells you the relationship between input size and time. But the actual time depends on the time of the individual steps, not how the time increases with input size. A quadratic algorithm may be faster than a logarithmic algorithm for moderate size input if the steps are faster.

Offhand, Python-level calls are relatively expensive. In your second solution, you're calling min() once for every leaf in the tree. In the first solution, you don't call min() at all - just sort() once at the very end. The internal implementation of sort() can fire off comparisons at a far higher rate than Python-level code can.
For more, replace return sorted(words)[0] with return min(words) - there's no need at all to sort. And that still may be slower! Don't know - try it. The under-the-covers confounder is that sort() pre-analyzes the list to see if it can find a faster, type-specific way to fire off compares (and, for type str, it can). min() does not do this - on every compare it does it starts over from scratch looking at the types of the comparands and deducing which specific comparison function needs to be called. That takes time, over and over.
All that said, the worst "theoretical" aspect of your code, which applies to both solutions, is repeatedly doing [::-1]. Reversing a string takes time proportional to its length, which can overall yield O(n**2) expense for a tree with n nodes. But reversal is fast, so that may not matter unless the tree grows very deep. Something similar for appending a character at every level: each time takes time proportional to the length of the string so far.
An alternative is to use a non-local collections.deque() of characters, and prepend characters via .appendleft() on the way down, and remove via .popleft() on the way up. Those are O(1) operations, no reversals are needed, and only one deque-in-progress is in memory. Because deques are sequences too, they also support lexicographic comparisons. When you find a new min, use deque_object.copy() to bind a copy to a non-local "overall winner" variable name.

I don't understand the "which can overall yield O(d * log d) expense for a tree of depth d", can you explain?

Right, that should say n instead of d, where n is the number of nodes. I'll edit. A complete binary tree with n nodes has about n/2 leaves, at depth about log2 n. Then it follows from reversing about n/2 strings each of length about log2 n.

Ok, that's part of what I thought. The other part is that that's only for a balanced tree. In general it's not O(n log n) but O(n^2).

Disagree about that - I believe a balanced tree is the worst case for reversal cost. For example, picture the other extreme, a tree with only 1 node at each level. Reversal will take O(n) time, but there is only one leaf node, so it's only done once.
The asymptotics for reversal cost (done only at leaves) differ from append-a-character cost (done at every node,, leaf or not).

Picture a tree with exactly two nodes at each level, one of them a leaf. Or take your 1-node-per-level tree and replace its leaf with a complete tree of n more nodes.


the second implementation is 5ms slower overall

Not true.
You didn't measure that properly. It's only about 0.3 ms slower. Here are times for running each solution on each input 1000 times, three submits for each solution, alternatingly. You can see the first solution takes about 3.1 ms while the second takes about 3.4 ms:


why is LeetCode telling me that the second implementation is 5ms slower overall?

Because LeetCode's testing is bad. Too few or too small test cases, and if you see a 5 ms difference, that's almost certainly just random variance of just judge time. Remember your solutions took around 3 ms while the judge likely randomly takes somewhere between 30 and 50 ms:

If you submit your solutions as-is a few more times, you'll likely be told various different times, and about half the time the second solution will have the faster time. Because the times of your solutions barely matter at all for the times you're shown. The 0.3 ms difference is insignificant compared to 20 ms random variance.
Avoiding min brought the second solution down to about 2.8 ms, and further adding a return brought it down to about 2.7 ms:
            if not node.left and not node.right:
                nonlocal shortest
                current = (string + d[node.val])[::-1]
                if not shortest or current < shortest:
                    shortest = current
                return

How I tested:
class Solution:
    
    def smallestFromLeaf(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> str:
        for _ in range(1000):
            result = self.real_smallestFromLeaf(root)
        return result

    def real_smallestFromLeaf(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> str:
        YOUR SOLUTION HERE

